# Help converting from WinForm to Windows-Mobile

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile

I have this code in my Winform C# program:

```
sb.Append(Encoding.Default.GetString(new byte[] { b }));
```

and it works **excellent**.

When I try it on my C# Windows-mobile program, I get this error:

```
No overload for method 'GetString' takes '1' arguments
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in MS documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getstring(v=VS.80).aspx

The method you are using is not presented in .NET Compact Framework (Windows mobile). You will need to use the second version that needs 2 more parameters: Index and Count.

Comment: @ Gali, awwww cmon you can figure it out! You just need the index to start from and the amount of stuff in the array. You already have in your code all the information you need! :)

Answer (score 0):

The Full .NET Framework is pretty big, too big for a small device. Therefore when they created the Compact Framework they had to cut some of the APIs. What resulted was a pretty brutal trimming for CF 1.0 and they've slowly added stuff back in over the years.

Sometimes as you just have, you'll encounter an API that is missing a particular override. The answer [as Eden said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779692/help-converting-from-winform-to-windows-mobile/4779781#4779781) is to use a different override that is supported. In this case:

```
Encoding.GetString (Byte[] toDecode, Int32 indexOfFirstByteToDecode, 
  Int32 numberOfBytes)
```